# SQL Database transactions and PRAM/FIFO consistency

Tags: sql, transactions, consistency

Do databases provide PRAM consistency ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRAM_consistency ) for transactions for multiple clients.

Example:
Assume we have two tables X and Y each with single record and single column Value of type int, initially set to 0.

Two clients connect to the database.
Client 1 does

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE X SET Value = 1
COMMIT
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE Y SET Value = 1
COMMIT
```

Client 2 does

```
SELECT TOP 1 Value FROM Y // statement 1
SELECT TOP 1 Value FROM X // statement 2
```

Let's assume, that statement 1 yielded value 1 from table Y. Is it guaranteed by RDBMS (lets say MS SQL Server), that under that condition statement 2 will always yield 1 form table X?

In other words, will other clients always see transactions committed by some client in the same order, in which that client committed them?

More general question: exactly what type of consistency is guaranteed by RDBMSes, if it is not PRAM?

Answer (score 0):

> Do databases provide PRAM consistency (
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRAM_consistency ) for transactions for
>   multiple clients.

Kind of. The direct consistency model appears to be [atomic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28programming%29). (But see below.) SQL databases have broader concerns than just what happens in RAM.

> exactly what type of consistency is guaranteed by RDBMSes, if it is not PRAM?

[ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID): atomic, consistent, isolated, and durable.

*Consistent* here doesn't mean the same thing that *consistent* means in concurrency models. Here *consistent* means that a transaction changes a database from one valid state to another valid state. Neither successful nor failed transactions can leave the database in an invalid state.

For example, if you have a constraint that says email addresses in "users"."email_address" must be unique, a successful transaction can't write a duplicate email address into that column. Neither can an *unsuccessful* transaction.

And neither can a transaction that was *still executing* when somebody killed the database server.

[Transaction isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) is the ACID concept closest in behavior to PRAM consistency, I think. A SQL dbms typically has several options for setting the isolation level of a transaction.

[SQL Server's options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Well, a simple answer is that the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level implies total consistency. So yes, under that model a compliant RDBMS will provide PRAM guarantees.

Your use of transactions is confusing in the question. It seems that a "client" is to you what a "transaction" is to the PRAM model/Wikipedia page. The explicit transactions in the question seem to serve no purpose.

For SQL Server, the answer is yes. Statement 2 will always read 1 provided that statement 1 read one. This is true for all isolation levels.

The SQL Standard, however, does not mandate this! `READ COMMITTED` can be satisfied by reading committed data from wildly varying points in time, for example. This is not causally consistent.